# How to avoid Autofill feature not creating a blank space

Tags: autofill, password-autofill

Looks like the default behavior of the smart suggestion is to add a space after the provided text. And that is not cool for example when you are trying to reset your password.

Is it possible to somehow to trim this blank space (in mobile web browser settings or anywhere)?

Could someone please advise? We don't want to off this feature just to avoid blank space

Thanks

Comment: you wanna use smart suggestion with passwords?

Comment: no, but when you for example want to reset your password. and you need to put your first and last name. And the Last name is Smith, with the autofill it will be "Smith " . Is it clear now? –

Comment: The only way I'm aware of that avoids this issue is disabling the feature for the textfield in question. Surely autofilling doesn't make much sense for field accepting a password?